# matrix -for and -each statements vba

Tags: arrays, vba, file, matrix, directory

I was previously helped and shown arrays here [specific file types in specific folders with vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088192/specific-file-types-in-specific-folders-with-vba/31088710#31088710) I want to develop this into a matrix as I also have several folders that contain these subfolders

This part is what I imagine the matrix would look like
The only examples I have seen suggest using a table in excel which vba that can move through it using -next command for (x,y) co-ordinates of it.  I was wondering if there is a way to do this through syntax in vba without referring to a table in excel?

```
upperFolders = Array("foldernames1", "foldernames2", "foldernames3",
folderNames1 = Array("Folder1", "Folder2", "Folder3")
folderNames2 = Array("Folder4", "Folder5", "Folder6")
folderNames3 = Array("Folder7", "Folder8", "Folder9")
mainFolder = "C:\xxxxxx\"
```

The full code given to me in the previous post with the matrix

```
Dim Myfile As String, MyFolder As String, NewFile As String, SubFolder As String

Sub SpecificFileTypeInSpecificFolders()
'
Dim myFile As String
Dim subFolder As Variant 
Dim folderNames As Variant
Dim mainFolder As String
```

'would like to replace the below with a matrix

```
folderNames = Array("Folder1", "Folder2", "Folder3")
```

'rest of code as it was given

```
mainFolder = "C:\xxxxxx\"

For Each subFolder In folderNames
    MsgBox subFolder
    myFile = Dir(mainFolder & subFolder & "\*.csv")
    Do While myFile <> ""
        MsgBox myFile
        myFile = Dir
    Loop
Next subFolder

End Sub
```

Comment: not quite clear what you mean by "matrix". Do you mean a 2-dimensional array that can be iterated over with nested for loops?

Comment: Yes, sorry that's what I meant a 2-dimensional array in VBA.  I have common subfolder names in other folders so the code would ideally pick out the same sets of subfolders

Comment: I gave an answer below -- though I wonder if what you really could use is a dictionary whose keys are the contents of upperFolders and whose values are the arrays you are currently storing in separate variables ( folderNames1 etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean this sort of thing?:

```
Function MakeMatrix(ParamArray Arrays() As Variant) As Variant
    'assumes that function is passed a collection of 0-based arrays
    'all with the same upper bound
    'returns a 0-based 2-dimensional variant array with the same values
    Dim Matrix As Variant
    Dim m As Long, n As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    m = UBound(Arrays)
    n = UBound(Arrays(0))
    ReDim Matrix(0 To m, 0 To n)
    For i = 0 To m
        For j = 0 To n
            Matrix(i, j) = Arrays(i)(j)
        Next j
    Next i
    MakeMatrix = Matrix
End Function

Sub test()
    Dim folderNames1, folderNames2, folderNames3 'all variant
    Dim myMatrix As Variant
    folderNames1 = Array("Folder1", "Folder2", "Folder3")
    folderNames2 = Array("Folder4", "Folder5", "Folder6")
    folderNames3 = Array("Folder7", "Folder8", "Folder9")
    myMatrix = MakeMatrix(folderNames1, folderNames2, folderNames3)
    Debug.Print myMatrix(1, 1)
    Debug.Print myMatrix(2, 2)
End Sub
```

Output:

```
Folder5
Folder9
```